# Cancan Ruby Rails Hash Associated Conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I am trying to prevent a user from accessing a profile that is not his/hers. My UserProfile model is linked to my profile model and has a column pertaining to the user_id. My thought was use cancan and "if a user.id does not match up with the associated user_id from the user_profile" then reject. I have tried to do this in so many different combinations and permutations and have only gotten cancan to reject if use the id field correlating to the UserProfile.

With the code below I can access

```
http://localhost:3000/users/8/profile and http://localhost:3000/users/6/profile
```

so the user has permission to see "use the show method of the UserProfile" of any user. So results are fetching properly but cancan is not limiting permissions based on the current User.id

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :registered
      can :show, UserProfile, :user_id => user.id 
    end
  end
end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :DOB, :user_id, :address_city, :address_country, :address_state, :address_street, :address_zip, :avatar, :first_name, :gender, :last_name, :position, :time_zone, :years_played
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_profile, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Route File

```
get    '/users/:user_id/profile/'  =>   "user_profiles#show", :as => :user_profile
```

UserProfile Controller

```
class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController

 load_and_authorize_resource
 def show

    #@user = User.accessible_by(current_ability) 
    #@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    #@profile = @user.user_profile


    @profile = UserProfile.where(:user_id => params[:user_id]).first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @profile }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `can :read, UserProfile, :user_id => user.id`?

Comment: I tried :read and :show and both allow user to see other profiles they don't below too.

Comment: Does the user have "registered" role?

Comment: yep, If I remove the "can :read, UserProfile, :user_id => user.id" from ability where the user is "registered", cancan does not allow the user to access UserProfile at all. So cancan is acting correctly but it seems like ":user_id => user.id" is not working in the can line.

Comment: Can you find out anything from the the queries that get fired when you invoke the action?